# Python facebook-sdk: retrieving names of users who posted a message on a page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-page

I want to use the Python facebook-sdk library to retrieve the names of the persons who posted a message on a Facebook page I created.

This is an example, returned by the Graph API explorer:

```
{
"feed": {
  "data": [
  {
    "from": {
      "name": "Ralph Crützen",
      "id": "440590514975673"
    },
    "message": "Nog een test.",
    "created_time": "2015-10-17T19:33:30+0000",
    "id": "649463214822976_649745285127205"
  },
  {
    "from": {
      "name": "Ralph Crützen",
      "id": "440590514975673"
    },
    "message": "Testing!",
    "created_time": "2015-10-16T20:44:17+0000",
    "id": "649463214822976_649492455153388"
  },
... etc ...
```

But when I use the following Python code...

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object('tinkerlicht')
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed')
print(posts['data'][0]['message'])
print(posts['data'][0]['from']['name'])
```

...only the *message* value is printed. Printing the *name* of the person who posted the message gives the error:

```
    print(posts['data'][0]['from']['name'])
KeyError: 'from'
```

At first, I thought that I needed the `read_page_mailboxes` permission. To use this permission, it has to be approved by Facebook, so I submitted a request. But Facebook replied:
"You don't need any additional permissions to post to Pages or blogs that you administer. You only need to submit your app for review if your app will use a public-facing login."

So what exactly is the reason I can't retrieve the `from` data from the messages feed? (While reading it from the Graph API explorer works fine...)

Btw, I'm using a page access token which never expires. I generated this token the way it's described [here](http://appdevresources.blogspot.sg/2012/11/retrieving-facebook-page-id-and.html).

Comment: `from` is not a scalar value, but an object itself.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't something like the following been printed? {
      "name": "Ralph Crützen",
      "id": "440590514975673"
    }

Comment: How should I know – if you’re not even mentioning what the exception you’re getting says …?

Comment: The payload is readable by `json.load( file)` (when the above content is saved to a file) What is so special about graph.get_connections() ?

Comment: There is noting wrong with the code; it's the permissions set to the access token. When I use a short-lived access token by selecting "Graph API Explorer" on the top right of the Graph API explorer page, it works! But when I use the never-expiring access token which is connected to a facebook-app I created, it fails. It might be better to post a new question about how to get the right permissions set to a never-expiring access token.

Comment: The answer is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280865/what-permissions-do-i-need-to-read-the-names-of-the-users-who-posted-to-a-face/33281284#33281284